# Create new table in exsiting sqlite database with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have a VB.Net app that was created and has about 2 years of data in a SQLite DB
I designed the scheme of one of the multiple tables wrong now my search functions incorrectly.
The table has all the columns set to TEXT data.
So I need a new table with some columns set to INTEGER.
I tried creating a new table that is not permitted.
OK so delete the DB from the app and write the old data to the new and improved table.
**The issue is where to I put the old DB with its table so I can write the data to the new table?**
I have looked at the ATTACH syntax but do not see how that works for my issue?
I have tried to use the cmd statement but my Windows 7 tells me it can't fine sqlite3
I am not real good with cmd line programming so that is a non starter sorry.

**So the question is how to create a new DB and move data from the old DB with VB.Net**

```
Public Sub makeTxData()

    'create table TxDataTable String for cmd
    Dim create_table As String = String.Empty
    create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TxData(
                    TID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    txSortDate TEXT,
                    txYear TEXT,
                    txType TEXT,
                    txAmount TEXT,
                    txCKNum TEXT,
                    txDesc TEXT,
                    txBalance TEXT,
                    txSearchMonth TEXT)"

    Dim dbTable As String = "TxDataTable"
```

I want this table with txYear and txSearchMonth to be Integers

Comment: You shouldn't even be creating a new table, never mind a new database. Just create the new column. Alter the table and add the new column, update the table and set the new column based on the old one, alter the table and drop the old column.

Comment: @jmcilhinney OK I understand How do I add a column to the table and then move the data in the old table to the new table I have DB Browse NOT sure I can use that SQL statement to add column to existing table in the app Will do a little searching Thanks

Comment: @jmcilhinney I added column code  I would like to change

Comment: attach + `insert into foo select ...`?

Comment: Though for the most part there's no real significant difference in use between a text column and an integer column. Sqlite will convert values back and forth as needed.

Comment: @Shawn While that is true the issue is the sql search finds data in the table FYI the column has numbers 1 to 12 so when I search Jan = 1 to Mar = 3 it brings Oct = 11 along so the search fails I wrote another test app with the txSearchMonth as INTEGER and that resolved the issue FWIW

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to try to write a Button Click Code for this SO
I used DB Browser to view the Database and executed two commands in this order
DB Browser has a tab named Execute SQL
[DB Browser Link](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)
First

```
ALTER TABLE TxData ADD NxData INTEGER
```

TxData is the table name and NxData is the new column for INTEGER's

Second Move the data in column txSearchMonth to the new column NxData

```
UPDATE TxData SET NxData = txSearchMonth
```